# iOS 9 Navigation Bar Under Status Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

[image]

How do you prevent the navigation bar from going under the status bar, and respect the status bar's space?

Comment: Do you want to hide Status bar or start navigation bar below status bar?

Comment: I am trying to start the navigation bar below status bar

Comment: then, it's better to create your own NavigationBar View

Answer (score 1):

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

Comment: Again, not trying to hide the status bar, I want the navigation bar below it

Answer (score 1):

If your app uses a `UINavigationController` with every view,when a `UINavigationController` is present, the `UINavigationBar` will automatically be placed below the status bar (the standard 20 point offset from the top of the screen that we are accustomed to from previous iOS versions).

[Check this link for details](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/09/developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar/)

If you don't want the status bar hide it.

Comment: I don't believe what you said is true, because I am using a UINavigationController, but the navigation bar is not being placed below the status bar, as you can see from the picture.

Comment: Status Bar is now part of your navigation bar. Prior to iOS 7 we have 44px navigation bar height now its 64px . You can verify this in your nib. Select your view, in your attribute inspector , set your top bar to opaque navigation bar and your view size to any iPhone device size you will see that it will minus the 64px from the devices height and give you the rest of  the space.

Answer (score 1):

In the viewController you want to hide the satusBar:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Not trying to hide the bar, I want the navigation bar below it.

Comment: Normal view won't cover the status bar because these are in the same window and the status bar is the top level, but you can add the view to a new window then set  newWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert.